# I want to find out the magnetic field strength of neodymium N35 grade magnet

Tags: magnetics

I am making a horizontal axis wind turbine. I have neodymium N35 magnets. I want to find out the magnetic field strength of one. Its dimensions are 50mm x 25mm x 12mm.

Comment: Assuming your question is "how do I measure a permanent magnet's field strength?" have you Googled "measuring magnetic field strength?"  Lots of references: https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project-ideas/Elec_p030/electricity-electronics/measure-magnetic-fields

Comment: The only reason you need the field strength of the magnets is to compute the voltage that should be generated in the coils. Perhaps the easiest way to measure the field strength of the magnets, or at least the *effective* field strength of the magnets, is to build them into a generator and measure the voltage produced in the coils at any give speed.

Comment: Thanks Neil_UK.